# Use stars and bars to find how many "SPIN"s.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

[image]

For this question, I don't understand why we only need to only two digits from these $4$ values. Can someone give an explicit example to demonstrate that?

Comment: The author is saying that since you have a $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$ already, you just need to choose two additional digits (with repetition allowed) from the four digits $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$ since knowing how many times each digit appears completely determines the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is saying that if a SPIN begins with $3$ and ends with $6$, then the requirement that $d_{i + i} - d_k = 0$ or $1$, $i = 1, \ldots, 5$, means that all four digits $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$ are represented.  Since only these digits are represented and the SPIN has length $6$, we need two additional digits selected from the digits $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$, with repetition allowed.  The number of such digits is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 2$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $x_k$, $3 \leq k \leq 6$, represents the number of occurrences of the digit $k$.  A particular solution corresponds to the insertion of three addition signs in a row of two ones.  For instance,
$$1 + + 1 +$$
represents the solution $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 1$, and $x_6 = 1$ (the number $3\color{blue}{3}45\color{blue}{5}6$), while 
$$+ + + 1 1$$
represents the solution $x_3 = x_4 = x_5 = 0$ and $x_6 = 2$ (the number $3456\color{blue}{66}$).  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can insert three addition signs in a row of two ones, which is 
$$\binom{3 + 2}{3} = \binom{5}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the five symbols (three addition signs and two ones) will be addition signs.

As for the specific examples, they are 
$$3\color{blue}{33}456, 3\color{blue}{3}4\color{blue}{4}56, 3\color{blue}{3}45\color{blue}{5}6, 3\color{blue}{3}456\color{blue}{6}, 34\color{blue}{44}56, 34\color{blue}{4}5\color{blue}{5}6, 34\color{blue}{4}56\color{blue}{6}, 345\color{blue}{55}6, 345\color{blue}{5}6\color{blue}{6}, 3456\color{blue}{66}$$
where I have highlighted the two inserted digits in blue.